# How to pass request object to method defined in generator.yml with table_method

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I pass request object to doJoin method which is configured in generator.yml?

generator.yml:

```
generator:
  param:
    config:
      list:      
        table_method: doJoin
```

ItemTable.class.php:

```
public static function doJoin(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias($q);

    return $q->select($rootAlias.'.*, p.currency_code, p.customer_price')
        ->innerJoin($rootAlias.'.Price p')
        ->where('p.currency_code = \'USD\'');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method `buildQuery()` in actions.class.php to accept the request parameter `...->$table_method($query, $this->getRequest()`:

```
protected function buildQuery()
{
  $tableMethod = $this->configuration->getTableMethod();
    $query = Doctrine::getTable('CLASS_NAME')
    ->createQuery('a');

  if ($tableMethod)
  {
    $query = Doctrine::getTable('CLASS_NAME')->$table_method($query, $this->getRequest());
  }

  $this->addSortQuery($query);

  $event = $this->dispatcher->filter(new sfEvent($this, 'admin.build_query'), $query);
  $query = $event->getReturnValue();

  return $query;
}
```

Then you change `ItemTable.class.php`:

```
public static function doJoin(Doctrine_Query $q, sfWebRequest $request)
```

Comment: Error: Couldn't find class CLASS_NAME

Comment: you have to change `CLASS_NAME` with the real name of your class `Item` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('whatever_you_want');
```

Comment: hm... it returns null: sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('main_item.filters'). As you see, I'm trying to grab the value from filter.